# Access denied when calling API for 'social.following'

Tags: sharepoint-online

I'm creating an add-in that lists all the sites a user has followed and I'm using the 'social.following' API to do this.
I have full control and everything, but I am getting this error:

```
<m:error xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
<m:code>-2147024891, System.UnauthorizedAccessException</m:code>
<m:message xml:lang="en-US">
Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource.
</m:message>
</m:error>
```

Any idea as to how to get this to work?

Comment: Are you using SharePoint app or just a CEWP with JS?

Comment: @sekhar SharePoint app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We've found the issue. It was because `_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl` brings back `sampleSite-<random-string>.sharepoint.com` instead of `sampleSite.sharepoint.com`

We had to get the correct URL by grabbing the query string parameter `SPHostUrl`

```
function getQueryStringParameter(urlParameterKey) {
    var params = document.URL.split('?')[1].split('&');
    var strParams = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i = i + 1) {
        var singleParam = params[i].split('=');
        if (singleParam[0] == urlParameterKey)
            return decodeURIComponent(singleParam[1]);
    }
}

var hostURL = decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter("SPHostUrl"));
```

Comment: You can use JSRequest.EnsureSetup(); JSRequest.QueryString.SPHostUrl  or 
GetUrlKeyValue('SPHostUrl'); to get the QueryString parameter values, But they are casesensitive, The function you have posted can be modified  not to be case sensitive.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need tenant administrative rights to do that. Site collection admin access won't suffice.

Reference:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163864.aspx#bkmk_AppPerms

Comment: I've made the change (http://i.imgur.com/yo4VItL.png) and reran it but I'm still getting the same error. Did I do it incorrectly?

Comment: Is the account you're using a site collection admin or a tenant/farm administrator account?

Comment: Just a site collection admin, do I actually need to log in as the tenant account? Is the permission addition I've added in the image required still then?

Comment: Yes, the application will need to run as the tenant account.


Don't forget about elevating applications privileges.
Ref: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/Mt210897.aspx

Comment: Got it. I'll try to get the tenant account information. In the mean time, once this add-in gets deployed, shouldn't every user have access to this and not just the tenant account? Also, my other question, on the image link in my first comment, I've added that permission scope. Is that still required?

Comment: Even with the tenant account, I am still seeing the same error. Here is my JS in case there's something wrong with it: http://pastebin.com/h4s8Ki68

Answer (score 1):

I would try to ensure that all needed SP js files are loaded before calling function:

`doJSON("/_api/social.following/my/followed%28types=15%29", renderSuccess, renderFail);`

I have the same code as yours working perfectly. The only difference is that I load the following files on demand first:

```
spSODAction(["sp.js", "sp.runtime.js", "sp.userprofiles.js", "sp.requestexecutor.js", "followingcommon.js"], function () {
   doJSON("/_api/social.following/my/followed%28types=15%29", renderSuccess, renderFail);
}
```

The function spSODAction allows to register multiple files:

```
var spSODAction = function (sodScripts, onLoadAction) {
   for (var x = 0; x < sodScripts.length; x++) {
      // Register any unregistered scripts
      if (!_v_dictSod[sodScripts[x]]) {
         SP.SOD.registerSod(sodScripts[x], '/_layouts/15/' + sodScripts[x]);
      }
   }

   SP.SOD.loadMultiple(sodScripts, onLoadAction);
}
```

The only other difference is that I am building the url as plain text (in my case, I want to retrieve the followed documents of the current logged in user:

```
var documentsUrl = currentAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/social.following/my/followed(types=2)";
```

Give it a try and let me know.